# Is there a name for the maxtrix resulting from $A^H*A$ where $\cdot^H$ is the adjoint operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a name for the matrix $B$ resulting from $A^H*A$ where $\cdot^H$ is the adjoint operator and $*$ the matrix product?

The resulting matrix would be hermitian, yet I do not know a name for the specific case where the $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ matrix is known.

Another related question would be : Are there specific numerical methods to compute $B$ (there probably are) knowing $A$.

Comment: In some contexts, this matrix is referred to as a [Grammian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix).

Comment: I am not aware of any methods for computing $B$ that are faster than the usual matrix multiplication.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks ! I totally forgot this.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, I assumed there would be some special methods as the output would be hermitian but maybe it is already handled by standard implementations

Comment: That's a good point; so at the very least one could cut the number of computations almost in half